# LINQ - Join with List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have condition where i have to join two different types of array to form a new array.

Let's see the class where condition should be created.

```cs
public class MutualFundParameter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AcNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class VoucherDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AcNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
}

public class VoucherMaster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VoucherDetails> VoucherDetails { get; set; }
}
```

New let's add some data into that object

```cs
// mutual fund parameter
var mutualFundParameters = new List<MutualFundParameter>
{
    new MutualFundParameter { Id = 1, AcNo = "001", CustomerName = "Ram" },
    new MutualFundParameter { Id = 2, AcNo = "002", CustomerName = "Shyam" },
    new MutualFundParameter { Id = 3, AcNo = "003", CustomerName = "Hari" },
    new MutualFundParameter { Id = 4, AcNo = "004", CustomerName = "Gita" },
    new MutualFundParameter { Id = 5, AcNo = "005", CustomerName = "Sita" },
};

// voucher details
var voucherDetails = new List<VoucherDetails>
{
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 1, AcNo = 001, Amount = 10.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 2, AcNo = 001, Amount = 120.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 3, AcNo = 002, Amount = 20.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 4, AcNo = 002, Amount = 120.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 5, AcNo = 002, Amount = 30.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 6, AcNo = 002, Amount = 20.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 7, AcNo = 003, Amount = 20.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 8, AcNo = 003, Amount = 20.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 9, AcNo = 003, Amount = 20.00M, MasterId = 1 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 10, AcNo = 004, Amount = 10.00M, MasterId = 2 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 11, AcNo = 005, Amount = 20.00M, MasterId = 2 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 12, AcNo = 006, Amount = 30.00M, MasterId = 2 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 13, AcNo = 007, Amount = 40.00M, MasterId = 2 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 14, AcNo = 008, Amount = 50.00M, MasterId = 2 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 15, AcNo = 009, Amount = 60.00M, MasterId = 2 },
    new VoucherDetails { Id = 16, AcNo = 001, Amount = 70.00M, MasterId = 2 },
};

// voucher
var voucherMasters = new List<VoucherMaster>
{
    new VoucherMaster
    {
        Id = 1,
        VoucherDetails = voucherDetails
                           .Where(x => x.MasterId == 1)
                           .ToList(),
        DateTime = DateTime.Now }
};
```

Now i need to join `MutualFundParameter` with VoucherDetails but that is inside a list of 'Voucher Master'
To join i have tried this but this doesn't work as expected

```cs
var res = voucherMasters.Join(
          mutualFundParameters,
          voucher => voucher.VoucherDetails.FirstOrDefault().AcNo,
          mutual => mutual.AcNo,
          (voucher, mutual) => new
          {

          }
);
```

Thanks Hoping for positive response.

Comment: Do you need to execute the join in database or in-memory?

Comment: in database but i put it for a sample

Comment: Why `AcNo` is `int` in `VoucherDetails`, but `string` in `MutualFundParameter`?
Also, please describe your database relations

Comment: It'd be better if you put db entities as sample, if these are the entities, what's the difficulty of directly joining VoucherDetails with MutualFundParameter based on acNo directly? If you want to additionally bring voucherMaster, you can have additional join of voucherDetails  wwith it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that AcNo is of the same type in both mutualFundParameter and voucherDetail, here are two examples querying either in-memory collection or db:
(Note: I've not compiled/run the code so please excuse any syntactical errors)

```
var resultFromInMemory = (
        from vd in voucherMasters.SelectMany(x => x.voucherDetails)
        join mfp in mutualFundParameters on mfp.AcNo equals vd.AcNo
        select new { vd, mfp });

var resultFromDb = (
        from vd in db.voucherDetails
        join mfp in db.mutualFundParameters on mfp.AcNo equals vd.AcNo
        select new { vd, mfp });
```

For in-memory collection since you're expecting voucherDetails to be a child collection of voucherMaster, performing a join between mutualFundParameters and voucherDetails requires that voucherDetails is first consolidated into a temporary single collection which .SelectMany helps with

In case of database (assuming relational db) no such intermediate collection would be needed as every entity is a flat table in there.